# Blackberry Push Production registration status 2

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, status, blackberry-webworks

I am using Blackberry PPG push to implement push enabled application, When I try my application with EVAL credentials, it works fine, get resgitered and receives push notifications.But when I edit credentials from Blackberrt Production service, I get registration response 2.  I can see my applicaion active on CP Admin portal.
Here are credentials I am using for production

```
var port = 3**19; 
var BBserverUrl = "http://cpxx2.pushapi.na.blackberry.com"; //listen-to URL
var appId = "**2-82aB8R8466e6i8r0M83582e2i64862aa29k1"; //unique app-id, provided by RIM
var max = 100; //max queue size
var wakeUpPage = "index.html"; //if the app is closed and push comes in, wake up here

blackberry.push.openBISPushListener(ops, onPush, onRegister, onSimChange);
```

Please help me getting it worked.

thanks in adnvance.

Comment: Are you sure you received a response code `2`. This does not seem to be a valid code. Please see list of valid codes here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/50897/push_response_codes_898622_11.jsp

Comment: Webworks is returning response code 2, which means rejected by server. But when I run same code with EVAL credentials, it returns 0, ie registred

Comment: Then make sure the URL you are using and the credentials are valid.The CPID is actually 4 digits. You are using 3. Can you verify?

Comment: Actually I was sent by blackberry, and they have specified CPID as well which is 3 digit. Shall I raise issue to blackberry to check weather CPID is correct?

Comment: I believe you should since your source code is working fine on EVAL credentials..

Comment: Do you know how to raise issue on blackberry?

Comment: I received a reply from BlackBerry through this email: `blackberrypushservices@blackberry.com`. I had requested for renewing my EVAL credentials. Try writing here.

Comment: did it worked for you? I meant Production credentials?

Comment: I have only worked with EVAL credentials as yet.

Comment: No response from Blackberry. Any other way of getting it worked?

Comment: No idea. Try replying to the same email you received the credentials from or applying a new set of credentials. Sorry no idea whatsoever..

Comment: @AniruddhAmbarkar i have worked with both eval and prod environments , and your credentials seems right. Make sure the push URL is correct, in production the url i use start with `https`.